# Dell Studio 1537 - Laptop keyboard issues

Tags: keyboard, dell

I had an old Dell Studio 1537 lying around and I decided to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 on it. I am completely new to Linux in general so I decided to go with Ubuntu due to its ease of use. Everything worked fine and I installed it successfully.

However all of a sudden when I turned it on the keyboard didn't work at all. When I plugged in an external USB keyboard it worked fine. I couldn't find a fix so I gave up and put the laptop away. I recently got it out again, booted it up and the laptop keyboard worked fine again, I turned it off then rebooted and then the laptop keyboard didn't work once again.

I am currently downloading Ubuntu 14.04.2 to mount it to a USB drive in order to install that on the laptop to see if that fixes it. Is there any keyboard drivers I need or something like that?

I have tried the following:

- turning off the laptop, removing the battery and AC, holding the power button for 30 seconds then rebooting. No sucesss

Thanks to whoever can help me with this issue!

**UPDATE 1 -** I decided to take the laptop keyboard out, I removed it from the laptop, gave it a good clean and ensured that the connection to the motherboard wasn't filled with dust etc... . I then started the machine and the keyboard worked, I restarted it multiple times and it worked every time. On the fifth time I booted from my USB with the 14.04.02 ISO ready for install and I started the machine again. It prompted me the install menu but the keyboard didn't work. I then took the USB out and booted the machine again but my keyboard didn't work once again.

**UPDATE 2 -** Updating to Ubuntu 14.04.02 has not made a difference.

**Could it be -** Can it be related to flea power, I've read that this often prevents keyboards from working. Also since the keyboard worked after being off the adapter for a while and after I opened up.

Comment: This issue has not been resolved yet.

Comment: I still require assistance!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu...  I'm sorry to say, but if the internal keyboard doesn't work, and an external one does, it looks like a hardware problem...  could you type the following command: `lsusb&sleep 10&lsusb` after you press [enter], remove the external keyboard, wait 10 seconds, try typing something and if it doesn't work, plug the external keyboard back in and post the output of the command...